# Eeeek! Where did my giant quotation mark go?

Tags: support, css

I don't care what @nohat thinks. The world is a bleak and barren place without ornamentation.

Less is less. Deal with it.

Comment: ❧❧❧ ♡♥♡ +1 ♥♡♥  〠☂          ☃

Comment: @nohat: Too little, too late. And stop trying to cheer me up.

Comment: I got your HEAVY DOUBLE COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENTs right here: 【❝ ❞】

Comment: @nohat: I have given my reply below.

Comment: +1:  "Less is less.  Deal with it."

Comment: Took me a while to figure out what the heck all this is about.

Comment: Isn't this question a little unproductive??????????

Comment: @J.Walker: Welcome to ELU meta. Sometimes we fool around in here.

Comment: Oh, I can see *that*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: "You can't hurt me, @nohat," said Robusto]

> And here is a bleak and barren statement. Any questions?

Comment: Is that a blockquote?

Comment: I kicked it around the block, yes.

Answer (score 20):

I am still seeing the quotation marks.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Brb, patenting scrollable adhesive tape.

Comment: I think your scrap of paper is upside-down, kiamlaluno.

Comment: @Martha No; the font prints _"_ like that.

Comment: +1 purely for including a picture of the answer in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Oh nuts, I liked those things! I wanted something like 'em on the trilogy, really — the blockquote boxes look far too generic without some sort of decoration...

Answer (score 5):

> ## ☃
>
> *“I may introduce all of my quotations with meaningless ornamental headers now.”* — Jon Purdy